# Solving for an integration problem with a variable boundary in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to solve for a simple integration function in r with the boundaries going from `0 to x`. I'm using the cubature package but I'm not sure how to properly write for it because the upper limit is not registering as a variable.

This is my code:

```
f <- function(x) {24/(x^3)}

F <- cubature::adaptIntegrate(f,lowerLimit=3,upperLimit = x)
```

and the error is:

```
Error in cubature::adaptIntegrate(f, lowerLimit = 3, upperLimit = x) : 
  lowerLimit and upperLimit must have same length
```

Comment: As you've written your code, `x` is undefined at the time `adaptIntegrate` is called.  That's what's causing your error.  How does your upper limit vary?

Comment: what do you want your F to be? a function? an expression? A number?